# aumentar tamanho do Varchar(255) - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, varchar

Tenho um banco de dados PostgreSQL aonde site e webservices tem acesso, hoje tenho um campo "Observacoes" que esta como varchar(255), preciso aumentar esse valor pois está dando erro quando o usuário coloca um texto maior no campo.

Primeiramente: posso aumentar esse valor para 500 (por ex.)? Eu já li que o tamanho máx. do varchar era de 255 mesmo (mas não tenho certeza dessa informação).

Segundamente: Eu precisaria parar o site/sistema e todo o servidor que acessa esse banco pra fazer o "ALTER TABLE NOME_DA_TABELA ALTER COLUMN NOME_DO_CAMPO VARCHAR(500)"

Eu sei que eu poderia usar o tipo "Text" que não tem limite de caracteres, mas eu precisaria fazer essa alteração no banco "de preferencia" sem ter que parar tudo (sistemas/ws).
Não tenho experiência em banco, então ja peço desculpas se não fizer muito sentido a pergunta...

Agradeço, muito obrigada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

O VARCHAR possui um tamanho máximo de 65535 caracteres. Então, pode-se alterar para VARCHAR(500) sem problemas. Referência do postgres varchar: https://www.javatpoint.com/postgresql-varchar

Quanto a reiniciar o servidor da aplicação, possivelmente não será necessário. Caso a sua aplicação limite no código os 255 caracteres aí sim terá necessidade de reinicia-la com a nova implementação de limite.

A alteração de coluna poderá ser realizada da seguinte forma:

`ALTER TABLE NOME_DA_TABELA ALTER COLUMN NOME_DO_CAMPO TYPE VARCHAR(500)`

Comment: Vinicius agradeço demais a ajuda! Na classe java a referencia a esse campo ("Observacoes") está como "String" apenas, fazendo esse ALTER TABLE diretamente no PostgreSQL (usamos DBeaver aqui) vc acredita que não será necessário parar o servidor/sistemas?

Comment: Acredito não ser necessário reiniciar, já que não possui a limitação por caracteres.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigada, me ajudou muito. Sucesso!